# I would like to know if there is a way to check in Javascript if a bitmap image is a valid mask image?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to place a main bitmap on canvas (jpg,png) and I also want to upload a bitmap file that is going to perform as a mask of the main bitmap.

I would like to know if there is a way to check in Javascript if a bitmap image is a valid mask image? (Like the uploaded image)

I have created a codepen and upload a mask image. If you upload a mask image, you can see the changes on main bitmap on canvas, and if you upload a non mask image nothing will change.  **I need to validade the mask image by code in some way**

```
`context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
maskInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    mask.src = URL.createObjectURL(maskInput.files[0]);
    mask.onload = function() {  
        maskImage.setAttribute('src', mask.src)
        isMaskValid(maskImage)
     draw()
    }
})

function isMaskValid(maskImage){
//   todo
}
//You can check all code here
https://codepen.io/thaisdsilve/pen/zYaENbx`
```

Mask:
(Definition of a "mask iage" in order to base the code: An image mask is a bitmap that specifies an area to paint, but not the color. Namely, a mask image is a monochrome image used to generate the alpha component of an original customer image pixel by pixel, in such a way that a black pixel (RGB 0,0,0) will generate a 100% transparent pixel in the final image (alpha 0), and a white pixel (RGB 255,255,255) will generate a 100% opaque pixel in the final image (alpha 255). Intermediate RGB values ​​in the mask image will generate semi-transparencies in the final image.)

[image]

Original image:
[image]
Result:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a definition of a "mask image" on which to base the code?

Comment: Definition of a "mask iage" in order to base the code:  An image mask is a bitmap that specifies an area to paint, but not the color. Namely, a mask image is a monochrome image used to generate the alpha component of an original customer image pixel by pixel, in such a way that a black pixel (RGB 0,0,0) will generate a 100% transparent pixel in the final image (alpha 0), and a white pixel (RGB 255,255,255) will generate a 100% opaque pixel in the final image (alpha 255). Intermediate RGB values ​​in the mask image will generate semi-transparencies in the final image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a mask image in the browser is detected by the (pseudo) code

```
maskInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
   mask.src = URL.createObjectURL(maskInput.files[0]);
   mask.onload = function() {  
       maskImage.setAttribute('src', mask.src)
       isMaskValid(maskImage)
       draw()
   }
})
```

- This appears to be loading the same mask image twice, doesn't look at its mime type and doesn't return for an invalid check.
- Although it may work without it, I would also suggest releasing the object URL after use, and setting image `src` values *after* adding their `load` event listener (instead of beforehand). Hence you could try something like

  ```
    maskInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if(maskInput.files[0].type != "image/png") {
            // invalid file type error
            alert('Error: mask file of type "image/png" expected')
            return;
        }
        const maskURL = URL.createObjectURL(maskInput.files[0]);
        maskImage.onload = function() {
            URL.revokeObjectURL( maskURL)
            if( isMaskValid(maskImage) {
                 draw()
            }
        }
        maskImage.src = maskURL;
    })
  ```
- To avoid race conditions between loading the main and mask images, I would suggest disabling the file input element held in `maskInput` until after the  main image element held in `bg` has loaded.
- Validity checking could now check if the `bg` (the castle) and `maskImage` elements have the same image dimensions using their `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties. It could also check if the mask image is a grey-scale file by writing it to a canvas and checking that the rgb values for pixels are the same -  and return a boolean status for the validity of the mask file.

Comment: You can even reduce that to `input.onchange = async (evt) => { const img = await createImageBitmap(maskInput.files[0]); if (isMaskValid(img) ...` All modern browsers now support this method and it's way more efficient than using an HTMLImageElement and a blob: URL.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the comment - unaware of `createImageBitmap` I have  used [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) in preference to`URL.createObjectURL` in the past. I hope the OP explores the option to use [`createImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) to answer what I believe to be a homework exercise.